# Show that a non-linear equation has exactly two roots

Tags: proof-writing, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, rolles-theorem

How can I show, that the following equation $xe^{-x} = e^{-3}$ has exactly two roots?

I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594196/how-to-show-that-an-equation-has-exactly-two-solutions) an answer, but it uses many other theorems as well, and we have not yet studied so advanced concepts. We studied only Rolles theorem.

Any help would be great, as I am stucked in this question for two days.

Comment: Write as $x=e^{x-3}$. Not that the right hand side has an always positive second derivative, and a first derivative both less than and greater than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = xe^{-x} - e^{-3}$.  The roots are the solutions to the equation $xe^{-x} - e^{-3} = 0$.  Now, $f'(x) = e^{-x}(1-x)$.  So, the derivative is zero only at $x = 1$.  Moreover, $f(1)>0$ and $f'(x)<0$ for $x>1$, which means that we have at most one root to the right of $1$.  Likewise, for $x<1$, $f'(x)>0$, which means that we have at most one root to the left of $x=1$.
We must also show that there is some $x>1$ such that $f(x)<0$.  Take, for example, $x=6$.  Also, we must show that for some $x<1$, $f(x)<0$.  Take for example $x=0$.  The Intermediate Value Theorem closes the deal.
Two roots total.