# Is it possible to solve an equation such as $x^2+5^x - 10 = 0$ without using graphical methods?

Tags: graphing-functions

I tried using logarithms to find the answer to $x^2+5^x-10=0$ but I didn't have any luck. Is there a way of solving the above equation algebraically, or do you have to use a graphical method?

Comment: Things of the form $A^x + x^2 + C =0$ involve the Lambert $W$ (read: graphical). 'Traditional' analytical methods are insufficient.

Comment: @Joe: You can use analytic methods to show there are exactly two real roots. Then, you can use a graph to identify them and use numerical methods like Newton's Method to find them.

Comment: It is possible to derive that the negative root of this expression can be approximated by the root of the polynomial $$x^{3}-3x^{2}+3x+61=0$$, where the real root is actually; $x=1-\sqrt[^3]{62}\simeq-2.9579..$. Not a very good approximation, but something that can be done without much numerical calculations.

Comment: @Moo How can I show that there are two real roots?

Comment: you can also see if you take $x=-\sqrt{10}$ Then $$(-\sqrt{10})^2+5^{-\sqrt{10}}-10=5^{-\sqrt{10}} \simeq 0.00616$$.

Comment: @Joe: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594196/how-to-show-that-an-equation-has-exactly-two-solutions

Comment: @Moo Thanks for sending me the link. I just researched the Lambert $W$. Does this count as a graphical function? Is there any way of algebraically finding the inverse of $f(x)=xe^x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the zero's of function$$f(x)=x^2+5^x-10$$ which is highly transcendental. The solutions would require numerical methods or special functions. Consider its derivatives
$$f'(x)=2 x+5^x \log (5)\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=5^x \log ^2(5)+2 \quad >0 \quad \forall x$$
The solution of $f'(x)=0$ is given in terms of Lambert function
$$x_*=-\frac{1}{\log (5)}W\left(\frac{1}{2}\log ^2(5)\right)\approx -0.413583$$ For this value $f(x_*)\approx -9.31500$ and this is a minimum (by the second derivative test); then two roots on each side of $x_*$.

Let me be lazy, and consider the expansion of $f(x)$ around $x=0$. This will give

$$f(x)=-9+x \log (5)+x^2 \left(1+\frac{\log ^2(5)}{2}\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$$ giving
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{\log(5)\pm\sqrt{36+19 \log ^2(5)}}{2+\log ^2(5)}$$ probably not very accurate but  sufficient to start Newton method. The iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & -2.3616508 \\
 1 & -3.3004059 \\
 2 & -3.1642570 \\
 3 & -3.1613032 \\
 4 & -3.1613018
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.6604150 \\
 1 & 1.3887413 \\
 2 & 1.3171449 \\
 3 & 1.3131011 \\
 4 & 1.3130890
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+5^x-10=0$

$x= ± \sqrt{10-5^x}$

$10-5^x=1, 4, 9$

$10-5^x=1$  ⇒ $x=\frac{log (9)}{log (5)}=1.36$

$10-5^x=4$  ⇒ $x=\frac{log (6)}{log (5)}=1.11$

$10-5^x=9$  ⇒ $x=\frac{log (1)}{log (5)}=0$

Non of these results satisfy the equation.But we can use try and error method.We can see that x must be between $1.36$ and $1.11$, we try $x=1.3$:

$1.3^2=1.69=1-5^x$  ⇒ $x=\frac{log 8.31}{log 5}≈1.3$

Comment: Why is $10-5^x$ one of $1,4,9$?

Comment: I'm not getting that; By saying $10-5^x={1,4,9}$, you're looking for integer solutions (if any). But then you're considering values like $1.36,1.11..$.

Comment: I wanted to show it can not have integer solution, then I found a rational one.